# "Not available for deploy for this organization" when adding a translation

Tags: managed-package, package, 2gp, translation-workbench

I have used Workbench Translate to translate my managed package to Spanish. When I attempt to create a new package version with sfdx the command outputs:

> es: Not available for deploy for this organization

There are other questions regarding "Not available for deploy for this organization" in stackexchange but they seem to be unrelated to translations.

my project-scratch-def.json includes the following:

```
"settings": {
    "languageSettings": {
      "enableTranslationWorkbench": true,
      "enableEndUserLanguages": true
    }
  }
```

My sfdx-project.json has:

```
"sourceApiVersion": "57.0"
```

`sfdx version`:

```
sfdx-cli/7.206.6 darwin-x64 node-v18.15.0
```

Comment: Can you include the command-line invocation you're using to upload the package? Specifically, are you giving your project-scratch-def.json as the build org definitioN?

Comment: @DavidReed I am using this command: sfdx force:package:version:create --path force-app --loglevel debug --package FranFast_FCC --branch locacl --installationkeybypass --targetdevhubusername DEV_HUB_USERNAME --wait 20 --codecoverage --json

Answer (score 1):

David Reed provided the solution in his comment.

Adding `-f config/project-scratch-def.json` solved this error.